# Get array of key/value pairs from document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to return all the key/value pairs from a document as an array.

**Sample Doc :**

```
{key:"value", key2:"value2", key3:"value3"}
```

**Required Output :**

```
[{key:"value"},{key2:"value2"},{ key3:"value3"}]
```

Ive tried using the `$objectToArray` operator but it doesn't work for single documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },/** Convert object to array & iterate on each object */
          in: {
          /** Consider each object (k:...,v:...) as an array &
              convert back to actual object (k:v) & push to 'data' array field */
            $arrayToObject: [
              [
                "$$this"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_VQnv3HdHTy)